# Discord.js v13 , Read status of users and give/remove role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So it returns the error cannot read properties of `.includes` and idk whats wrong (v13 djs) can someone help and explain?

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', async (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
            const role = newPresence.guild.roles.cache.get('915254184046100540');
            const member = newPresence.member;
            const activities = member.presence.activities[0];
            
            if (activities && (activities.state.includes('Hi'))) {
                return newPresence.member.roles.add(role);
            }
            else if (member.roles.cache.get(role.id)) {
                newPresence.member.roles.remove(role);
            }
          });
```

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: activities.state may be undefined according to the docs, that's probably what happened here